# Find all eigenvalue for $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, computer-science

Let $V$ be the vector space of all converging real sequences, that is
$$V = \lbrace (a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) |\forall i \in \mathbb {N}: a_i \in\ \mathbb{R}\;\mathrm{and}\; \exists\! \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \rbrace$$

We are given this linear transformation:
$$ S:V \rightarrow  V,\; S(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) = (a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots)$$

---

Find all of the **eigenvalues** of $S$.

---

> MY METHOD:
>  In fact, $S$ "moves left". The linear transformation
> deletes the first member in the sequence.
>  I tried to find any
> $\lambda$ $\in\ \mathbb{R}$, such that there is a sequence  with at
> least one $a_i \neq 0$ that will satisfy: 
> $S(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots) = (\lambda a_1, \lambda a_2, 
>  \lambda a_3, \lambda a_4)$, 
> but without success to this moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $Sa = \lambda a$, for $a = (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in V$, implies that
$$\lambda a_i = a_{i+1}, \quad \forall i \in \mathbb N.$$
Therefore, $(1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots)$ is an eigenvector if and only if $-1 < \lambda \le 1$.

Comment: There is no need to consider the case $\lambda = 0$ separately

Comment: Note that we need $|\lambda| < 1$ i.e. $-1 < \lambda < 1$, not just $\lambda < 1$.

Comment: Yes thanks, I've edited.

Comment: Why not $\lambda = 1$ as well? The limit just needs to exist, right? Needn't be $0$.

Comment: Oh yes, good point.

Answer (score 3):

You need to solve $$S(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) = \lambda(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$$ i.e. $$(a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots) = (\lambda a_1,\lambda a_2,\lambda a_3,\ldots).$$

Now equate each element of those two sequences. We need $a_2 = \lambda a_1$, $a_3 = \lambda a_2$, $a_4 = \lambda a_3$, ....

Substitute the first equation into the second to get $a_3 = \lambda a_2 = \lambda(\lambda a_1) = \lambda^2 a_1$.

Substitute the second equation into the third to get $a_4 = \lambda a_3 = \lambda(\lambda^2 a_1) = \lambda^3 a_1$.

So the first four terms of the eigensequence are $a_1$, $a_2 = \lambda a_1$, $a_3 = \lambda^2 a_1$, and $a_4 = \lambda^3 a_1$.

Can you figure out the rest of the eigensequence? Don't forget that $\lambda$ needs to be such that the eigensequence converges.

Comment: Yes. thank you!